# SQLdeveloper automatically adds FORCE EDITIONABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to prevent that SQL Developer automatically adds `FORCE EDITIONABLE` to created views?

I create them via the view menu:

[image]

While editing there is no `FORCE EDITIONABLE`. But after I saved it and view the SQL code via the SQL tab I have the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "Databsename"."viewName" ("INFORMATION") AS
```

Is there a way to prevent this. I'm sure that when I started to create views the view creation was without force and the strings with my database name.

Comment: That's what `dbms_ddl` generates and that's what SQL Developer uses in the background. I don't think you can change that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I want to create a backup, should I save the version with "FORCE EDITIONABLE" or without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORCE` option is not a property of the view; it is only in the SQL because SQL Developer assumes that if you create the view again you will want to use the `FORCE` option. There are several ways to tell SQL Developer not to use that option in the generated DDL.

Not all SQL Developer dialogs give you an option, but if right-click on the view and select "Export", there is an option named "Add Force to Views".
[image]

Another way to prevent `FORCE` is to call `DBMS_METADATA` manually, like this:

```
begin
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'FORCE',false);
end;
/

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'TEST_VIEW') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version from "Compatible" to, for instance, 11.2.0, should remove the "EDITIONABLE" keyword, which was introduced in version 19 of the database.

Comment: Are you referring to the compatible database parameter or the "Version: COMPATIBLE" drop-down in Oracle SQL Developer? Modifying that parameter would be a large and dangerous change just to accommodate a small feature in one tool, and often impossible to change the parameter anyway. The "Version" drop-down on my version of SQL Developer (21.4.3.063) only has two values - "COMPATIBLE" and "LATEST".